# Problem with connecting split keyboard with sea-micro microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller, firmware, mechanical-assembly

First of all, I'm not sure that this issue has a place in this forum, if I'm wrong, please let me know and I'll post it where appropriate.

I have assembled a mechanical keyboard based on [helix](https://www.littlekeyboards.com/collections/helix/products/helix-pcb-kit). The rest of the components used are irrelevant to the post, except for the microcontroller:

Instead of the classic [elite-c](https://www.littlekeyboards.com/collections/mcus/products/elite-c-v3) controller, I have used the [sea-micro](https://customkbd.com/products/sea-micro-pro-micro-alternative) controller. Because the keyboard is split, I use a microcontroller on each PCB (one for each hand) and connect both parts using a TRRS cable.

By connecting the microcontroller by USB and testing each hand of the keyboard individually, the result is satisfactory. However, the problem comes when I connect one of them as a client via the TRRS cable. The one who plays the client doesn't work. It doesn't even turn on.

I have tried connecting other keyboards that I have with elite-c as a client and there are no problems. But keyboards with sea-micro never work as a client for me.

The firmware I have burned them in the same way using `qmk`:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --user qmk
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.local/bin
$ qmk setup
$ cd qmk_firmware
$ make helix/rev3_5rows:default:clean
$ make helix/rev3_5rows:default:dfu
$ qmk compile -kb helix/rev3_5rows -km default
```

Am I doing something wrong? for the rest of the keyboards it works perfectly for me, and it only fails me with sea-micro. Is it microcontroller problem?

EDIT: I add microcontroller image and TRRS connector. Be careful, in the case of the image it has an elite-c; in this case the problem is with sea-micro (I don't have a photo right now):

[image: PCB]

Comment: We don't know how you connected the MCUs together with TRRS connectors and what you communicate between them. Would you please give details in a way that someone could replicate what you are doing (or immediately see if it can or can't work).

Comment: I use the PCB's own structure for this, simply soldering the microcontroller and the TRRS connector. I have added an example image to the post.

Comment: OK, but we still don't know what it does. It likely connects power supply and serial data between keyboard halves. But you are using purchased electronic products with custom firmware. We have no schematics or firmware source code to analyze why they don't work. Maybe you just loaded incorrect firmware or the firmware of those boards you use have no support for using that connector. Have you tried any debugging what the problem might be?

Comment: The soldering looks pretty marginal to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, USB VBUS detection on sea-micro controllers doesnt work properly. The solution has been to indicate in the firmware headers ('config.h` the definition:

```c
#define SPLIT_USB_DETECT
```